# Sharepoint 2007 - link to individual sites' images in CSS

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to link to a image stored in the Images library of an individual site collection.

I am able to link to images in the root site collection folder using `url(../../Images/imagename.ext)`, however I want to link to the individual sites Images library, without directly inserting the site name.

I know this can be done easily enough in a page layout, using a dynamic token `#SPUrl:~site`

Is there an equivalent I can use in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Do your images need to change from site collection to site collection? If not, I put them into the 12\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\MyProject directory. I can then refer to the image in CSS as:

```
background-image: url(/_layouts/images/myproject/imagename.ext);
```

The virtual _layouts path insures that it will work for any depth on the server.